# How to use a custom icon for a stereotype in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect, stereotype, shapescript

I want to use my own icons for elements (nodes) in Enterprise Architect.

For certain stereotypes, there is a build in behavior in Enterprise Architect, that adds an icon in the upper-right corner of an element, like this (in this case the stereotype "server" is used):

[image]

[see [this page](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_deploymentdiagram.html) for a list of the default stereotypes].

Note that the position (offset from top and right) and absolute size of the icon are preserved, even when the shape is resized:

[image]

I want to display my own custom icons for my stereotypes, just like Enterprise Architect does. So i tried to use a shapescript to display the icon, but all drawing in shapescript seems to be relative to the shape's size. For example:

```
shape main {
    drawnativeshape();
    image("database", 87, 10, 92, 25);
}
```

Results in this:

[image]

The first one is stretched wrong, and while the second is better, that is just luck.

While using a "decoration" seems to preserve the size of the picture, it is always placed in the top left corner:

```
decoration icon {
    image("firewall", 0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

[image]

**So how do i add a custom icon, based on the object's stereotype, that is drawn correctly (always same size, always in top-right corner), like Enterprise Architect does?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. It is a decoration you want. To place it in the upper right corner use

```
orientation = "NE";
```

in the decoration shape.

Comment: That works, almost. It does move the icon to the top right corner of the drawing space, but it draws the icon over the cube's corner, instead of inside the cube.

Comment: That's because the actual corner of the shape is the outer corner of the cube, and that's where the decoration is anchored. So try changing the co-ordinates around. Negative values are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

My eventual solution (with thanks to @Uffe) is this:

```
decoration database {
    orientation = "NE";
    image("database", -60, 60, 40, 160);
}
```

[image]