# Using a custom icon set for stereotypes in Sparx EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a set of icons that I'd like to use in Sparx to replace the images of some elements. I have added them to the Images and can change the alternate appearance of an element to the desired icon, but this is tedious to do each time for each element.

What I've thought of doing is creating an MDG for this icon set and setting the image of each stereotype to be its own icon from the custom set. This way I can just drag each over from a toolbox.

After coming across the following post, I was able to somewhat achieve what I wanted: [How to use a custom icon for a stereotype in Enterprise Architect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611486/how-to-use-a-custom-icon-for-a-stereotype-in-enterprise-architect)

Except my icon is appearing offset from an invisible element instead of centered. The Shape Script I am using is:

```
shape main{
    image("panels", -30, 30, 80, 0);
}
```

The excellent ebook from Thomas Kilian identifies the parameters for 'image' as

```
Image(imageName,left,top,right,bottom)
```

but I for the life of me can't seem to find the right combination of numbers to center the icon directly in the center of my invisible element. And then I have 20 other icons/stereotypes to do the same thing with. Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The coördinates in shapescripts in EA work in a 0-100 square which represent relative positions on your shape.

`0,0` is the top left, and `100,100` is the bottom right.
So if you want your image to fill the whole shape you have to use

```
image("panels", 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Your code would show the image on the top left of the element, partially overlapping with the main shape dimensions.